# Make Discord DM a copy of messages

Tags: discord, discord.py

I Have a discord bot that is basically deleting posts that don't match a regex format.
It then DM's the user a quick message that includes the required format.

I am wondering if it'd be possible for the bot to send the user their original message as a second DM or part of the DM it is already sending out.

Here is the code

```
    if valid_check:
            if re.match(self.regex, message.content) or re.match(self.regex2, message.content) and not gutted:
                pass
            else:
                if not message.author.bot:
                    try:
                        await message.delete()
                        content = "Please use the following Format when posting:\n" \
                                  "[Location] [H] [W]\n" \
                                  "\nExample:\n" \
                                  "[USA-CA] Narnia [H] Faun Hoof" \
                                  "[W] Lions Tears.\n"
                        await message.author.send(content=content)
                    except:
                        pass
```

Comment: If you want to send the content in a second DM, just call `message.author.send` a second time with that message's content as the content. You've already accessed message content in this code snippet, and you've also sent a DM with some string content, so that should be quite trivial to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the original `message.content`, save it, and append it to your new `content` as you please.

Beware though, consider what happens if someone sends a message containing `@everyone`. You should sanitize the user input.

Comment: Yes. Also be careful of the character limit, and you can sanitize input using `AllowedMentions`

Comment: Considering he's sending these messages in the person's DM's I don't think it matters if there's an `@ everyone` ping in it, it's not gonna ping anyone anyways. If you relog the messages in a public channel this is a big concern, so a valid point to raise, but here it literally doesn't do anything.